# Raven's matrices

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Is anyone able to solve this matrix? It came up on a practice aptitude test I'm taking and this one in particular had me stumped.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spontaneously, I would say

> second alternative because exactly one of $\{←, ↑, ↓\}$ occurs as middle element of every row

and

> for each column, the two outer symbols contain exactly two occurences of a set of three symbols (in first column $\{↘,↓,↑\}$, in the second column $\{ ↙,→,←\}$ and in the third, $\{ →,↑,↗\}$).

Based on this,

> the second ($↑↓↑$) choice is the only possible.